# Resistive current measurement by novizon

Tags: labview

can anyone provide vi file of resistive current measurement as following block diagram?
[image: resistive current measurement]

Comment: How is this a programming (code) or programmers tool related question?

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible translate this image into code since it is not a LabView code snippet but just a plain image and you are missing the code for the sub-VI and the express VIs.
My suggestion would be to contact Novizon or any of the co-authors of the paper where this image is coming from on ResearchGate and hope they are willing to supply you with the VIs.